# Changing Post Tag Color Based On Post Count

Tags: posts, tags, conditional-tags

I have post tags that must always display. I want to change the color of the tag if there are no posts. I am looking for guidance on how to find the count and change the color of the post tag link depending on the post number. If the number is zero I'd like to change the tag link to be gray.

```
<div class="container">

<?php 
  $tags = get_tags(array(
   'hide_empty' => false,
   'count' => true
));

foreach ($tags as $tag) :?>
   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $tag->name ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $tag->name ); ?></a>

<!-- Ideally I could add a class to that <a> tag if the post count equals zero. Open to other solutions -->

<?php endforeach; ?>
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.  I just added a class using $tag->count.  Tested and works.

```
<div class="container">
    <?php $tags = get_tags(array(
       'hide_empty' => false,
       'count' => true
    ));

    foreach ($tags as $tag) :?>
        <a class="count-<?php echo $tag->count; ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $tag->name ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $tag->name ); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

This will add the class count-0 if there are no posts. so just add something similar to this CSS.

```
.count-0 {
    color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great. I did not even consider that kind of possibility and now it has me considering other useful ways to implement class changes in WordPress.

Comment: Your welcome & good luck!